# Is a method still "pure" if it invokes a designated callback given as parameter

Tags: functional-programming, terminology

Eg. `PureFoo(onSuccess: () => { DoSomething(); });` (example in C#)

Does `Purefoo` still counts as pure (without "side effects") if it invokes `onSuccess`? or is the method only "honest" (as in doesn't hide what it does)?

I've searched on Google but it didn't yield relevant results.

Comment: For clarification, are you asking if can a function be still pure if it invokes non-pure functions?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Yes, as in "is it still considered as pure if it does this" as C# does not enforce pureness unfortunately. Or is it to be avoided / technically not callable / qualified as pure anymore.

Comment: See this question on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300682/is-a-function-immediately-impure-if-it-takes-a-function-as-a-parameter#:~:text=The%20facet%20that%20output%20is,whether%20the%20parameters%20are%20pure.&text=This%20effectively%20means%20that%20for,invokes%20functions%20passed%20as%20arguments.).

Comment: Since C# does not have pure functions as a concept, if you think it is OK, does anything say otherwise?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Kinda matters to me bc I wish it did enforce it and I'm trying to abide by it when it's possible to produce cleaner/more robust code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen What I get from the question you linked is that my method is not really pure anymore. It can still be honest though as all side effects are explicit if the only side effect is contained in the passed argument.

Comment: A callback is just a function argument, there is nothing special about it. If the supplied function is impure than the calling function is impure as well. I don't think the pure caller-impure-callback approach per se is more explicit (or _honest_). This would only hold provided the side effect is apparent from the underlying type.

Comment: Purely (no pun intended) from Wikipedia's definition, "2. The function application has no side effects..." So if the side effects occur while the function application is taking place, the function cannot be pure.

Answer (score 0):

So, long story short, that sounds like a no.

If there are side effects, from whichever source, it shouldn't/can't be called pure.

However, I guess it can still be made more honest by limiting the side effects to only all clear & explicit intended callbacks which sorta ask as an alternative return + call based on returned values.
Note that you can't ensure the callback is called only when expected and the number of times it's expected, etc. still.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, `onSuccess` has a name and a signature (returning void/unit) that signals an *intentional* side effect. If your function doesn't do anything with the result of the `onSuccess()` call, then there isn't anything possible to pass into there that will make the outer call pure.

Comment: Wait… so… would it change something if `onSuccess` took parameters or solely if it did return something? also not sure to get your last sentence.

Comment: Purity is about how the function is implemented. It has nothing to do with the call site. I'm saying if you implemented `PureFoo`, the way `onSuccess` is defined, it can't be called in a pure way. A function that takes no parameters and that returns nothing has no other possible purpose than to be called for its side effects.